# How do I pass through an envrionment variable via npm script?

Tags: node.js, windows, automation, environment-variables, cypress

Here is my current package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^6.8.0",
    "cypress-tags": "^0.0.21",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress run",
    "cy:dev": "CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS=DEVELOP ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run"
  }
}
```

When I run **cy:dev** I get this error:

```
'CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However if I copy and paste the exact script and run it directly in the CLI, it works perfectly fine.

Is there any way to pass through a temporary environment variable via NPM script?

I think this WOULD work on Mac/Linux systems but I need it to work cross platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get around this by using a npm package.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "cypress": "6.8.0",
    "cypress-tags": "0.0.21",
    "typescript": "4.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cross-env CYPRESS_INCLUDE_EXCLUDE=IGNORE ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run",
    "cy:dev": "cross-env CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS=DEVELOP ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run"
  }
}
```

This works cross platform too.